# Matrix multiplication question for beginners

Tags: linear-algebra

Can please someone explain me how to get this result? I mean where the 10 came from the 2nd board I don't get it :/

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&6\\
3&0&3\\
1&1&4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\0\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}2+10+0\\6+0+0\\2+5+0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}12\\6\\7\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You have to multiply the second element of the first row of the matrix by the second element of the vector.

Comment: Ok but how the 5 of the 3rd row got produced? And why only zeros on the 3rd column? And how the 2 6 2 from the first column got produced? :/

Comment: I suggest you to see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuixY2bCc_0

Comment: It's high time that you learn how matrix multiplication is defined.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't know in English they're called matrix! Helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&6\\
3&0&3\\
1&1&4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\0\end{pmatrix}
=
\pmatrix{
\color{red}1 \cdot\color{blue}2
+\color{red}2 \cdot\color{blue}5
+\color{red}6 \cdot\color{blue}0\\
\color{red}3 \cdot\color{blue}2
+\color{red}0 \cdot\color{blue}5
+\color{red}3 \cdot\color{blue}0\\
\color{red}1 \cdot\color{blue}2
+\color{red}1 \cdot\color{blue}5
+\color{red}4 \cdot\color{blue}0
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just start with the first element, which is a sum, of the resulting vector.

$\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{ 1}&\color{blue}{2}&\color{blue}{6} \\ 3&0&3 \\ 1&1&4 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{ 2}\\ \color{blue}{5} \\ \color{blue}{0} \end{pmatrix}$

The first element of the first row is multiplied with the first element of the vector: $1\cdot2=2$

The second element of the first row is multiplied with the second element of the vector: $2\cdot5=10$

The third element of the first row is multiplied with the third element of the vector: $0\cdot6=0$

All these results have to be summed up.

Now the second element of the resulting vector.

$\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{ 1}&\color{blue}{2}&\color{blue}{6} \\ \color{red}{ 3}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{3} \\ 1&1&4 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\color{red}{ 2}\\ \color{red}{5} \\ \color{red}{0} \end{pmatrix}$

The first element of the  second row is multiplied with the first element of the vector: $3\cdot2=6$

The second element of the second row is multiplied with the second element of the vector: $0\cdot2=0$

The third element of the second row is multiplied with the third element of the vector: $3\cdot0=0$

I hope the systematic behind this multiplication is more obvious to you now.